# Toolbars icons not turning black

Tags: android, colors, toolbar

I want all the icons in my toolbar to be black in color. But with the code that I am using they remain white in color. What is my mistake?

styles.xml-

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     </style>
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"/>
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>)
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/BlackDrawerIconStyle</item>
     </style>


<style name="BlackDrawerIconStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>

</style>
```

Comment: just to confirm, you changed the theme in manifest, right?

Comment: The theme in manifest is @style/AppTheme

Comment: Do you set a theme on your `Toolbar`? By default with a light theme the icons should already be black.

Comment: I changed the theme now and that worked.That was such a silly mistake.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest define the theme to MyMaterialTheme to set your custom theme as default theme for the application like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
.....
```

Comment: This one changes only the hamburger icon to black.The rest remain white.

Comment: @ianhanniballake asked to change the theme of the toolbar and that worked.Anyways,Thanks to you too.